# File read and Write in C

Tags: c

I have tried to read the following input(comma separated) from a file which has the following format. But I don't know how to read from file. What I understand is, it is in string format here. How will I extract every digit within [] which is comma separated?

```
  File Input: **[1 2 3 4],[2 5 6]**
       Output:  1 2 3 4 2 5 6
```

If you have any idea or any tutorial regarding this will surely help me.

Comment: Loop through string, skip anything that's not a digit, print otherwise.

Comment: have you been reading some code examples for read files in C?, try with google!

Comment: @H2CO3:It means that I will read the whole line as a string from file. then I will follow what you say?

Comment: does number has one digit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;       

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {

     while ((c = fgetc(pFile)) != EOF)
     {
        if(isdigit(c))
           printf("%c ",c);
     }
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That should be `fgetc()`, shouldn't it? +1 for using it correctly, though.